# How to generate a list of names associated with specific letter grade using regex in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm starting with this code but it generates a list of only last names and letter grades in the format ['First Last: A']. What expression can I use to create a list of names associated with a letter grade A in the format ['First', 'Last'] with names extracted from only A letter grades? More specifically, I'd like to remove everything after the ': Grade' so that I only see the name. The data has other letter grades included. I think using \s and (?= ) could be helpful but I'm not sure where to place it.

```
   pattern = "(\w.+:\s[A])"
   matches = re.findall(pattern,file)
```

The file is a simple text file in this format:

First Last: Grade

I'd like the output to extract only names with a grade A in this format:

First Last

Comment: what does the file look like?

Comment: The file is a very simple text file that looks like this:

First Last: Grade
First Last: Grade
First Last: Grade
First Last: Grade

Comment: @TamaraQawasmeh maybe you should add more information about the input and output as you want.

Comment: @Ferris I added more information on the input and output. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: do you need to use `re`?

Comment: @TenaciousB Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ther are so much ways, depending on what you input data:

```
re.split(':', 'First Last: Grade')
# ['First Last', ' Grade']

re.findall('^(.*?):', 'First Last: Grade')
# ['First Last']

re.findall('^(\w+\s?\w*):', 'First Last: Grade')
# ['First Last']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `string.splitlines()` or split the lines into a list when you read the file, then use `string.split(': ')` to get the name and grade, no need to use regex unless it is a requirement for school or somehting:

```py
text = """
John Doe: 99
Jane Doe: 100
"""

grades = {line.split(': ')[0]: line.split(': ')[1]
          for line in text.splitlines() if ': ' in line}

print(grades)
```

Output:

```py
{'John Doe': '99', 'Jane Doe': '100'}
```